# Show that $ (x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto \ln \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i} \right)$ is convex in the positive orthant

Tags: convex-analysis

Show that the function $f : \mathbb{R}^n_{++} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}^n_{++} = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_i > 0 \right\}$, $$ f(x) = \ln \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i} \right)$$ is convex.

---

**My approach**

In the case of one dimension ($n=1$), the function $\ln(1/x)$ is convex by using the fact that

> A twice differentiable function of one variable is convex on an interval if and only if its second derivative is non-negative.

I am struggling to prove the case of two dimensions ($n=2$) and higher.  I tried to prove that

$$ \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y) \geq f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y)$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2_{++}, 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$, but the natural log function was in the way, and I am not sure if there is an equality that I can use to deal with it.

Comment: it might be easier to show that the Hessian is positive-definite.

Comment: @dezdichado I will try that. I have tried finding the second derivatives before, but they look really messy.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3412172/339790)

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function
$$
f(x) = \ln \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i}\right) 
$$
is convex if
$$
g(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i}
$$
is [log-convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_convex_function), and that is true because

- each function $g_i(x) =  1/x_i$ is log-convex (this follows from the one-dimensional case, $t \mapsto \ln(1/t)$ is convex), and
- the sum of log-convex functions is again log-convex, see for example [How to prove that the sum of two log-convex functions is log-convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/665768/42969) .

Answer (score 1):

Just commenting on the great answer of @Martin R.:

Why is the positive linear combination of log-convex functions again log-convex?

Let $\phi_1$, $\ldots$, $\phi_m$ convex functions, $c_1$, $\ldots$, $c_m > 0$.  We are to show that $\log (\sum_{i=1}^m c_i \exp \phi_i)$ is again convex.  Now this follows from :

1. $$\phi= (\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_m)$$ is convex
2. $$(y_1, \ldots, y_m) \mapsto \log (\sum_{i=1}^m c_i \exp y_i)$$ is convex and increasing (convex is equivalent to Hölder's inequality)
3. The composition of a convex and increasing function with a convex function is again convex.

Comment: Convex function (as I know it) are *real-valued* functions. What does “$\phi= (\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_m)$ is convex” mean in this context?

Comment: What you could say (I think) is: If $\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_m$ are convex functions and $h:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is convex and increasing in each argument then $h(\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n)$ is convex. Perhaps that would be a good addition to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/665768/42969 (which I used in my answer). You would still have to show that $h(y_1, \ldots, y_n) = \log (\sum_{i=1}^m c_i \exp y_i)$ is convex (which might be trivial or not).

Comment: @Martin R: that would be a definition overloading... we have the standard result that $f\circ g$  is convex when $f$ convex increasing, and $g$ convex; and it is useful to extend that to $g$ having values in higher dimensions...( some people study ordered linear spaces)  about $h$, it is convex due to C-B-S ineq or,trully, Hölder, worth checking it :-)

Comment: @MartinR:  your solution really got me thinking... and probably there are other angles to it... say you want to show that if $f_k$ are positive and log-convex then so is $\sum f_k$. Now log convex ( for fn of 1 var) means some matrix (with the derivatives of $f$ ) is  positive semidefinite and that behaves OK under positive linear combinations. What about for several variables?